# deep learning: How do I know my net is not memorizing

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have a convolutional neural network and my input data are 10.000 images of the same object from different views (angles in 3D around the image). My network converges, but I am not sure if the network has memorized all the different angles / views or not. Since I only have one object I cannot really check test it with different data.
My training / test plot looks like this (red trainig, green test):

[image]

Since the test is lower than training I expect the network to learn all the images by heart? Even though I have 10.000 kind of different images.

Comment: What is the vertical axis for testing -- failure rate as a percentage?

Comment: What is your scoring or classification function, that "ground truth" that gives it feedback?  What is the purpose of this model?  Is it supposed to recognize this one object as opposed to all others?  If so, then you need to give it counterexamples as well.

Comment: Well, it is a regression task so there is no "accuracy". The purpose is to recognize other objects as well ofc course, but I do not have more data than this one model, that is my problem. My ground_truth is a depth map.

Comment: veritcal axis for testing is to look at the ground_truth depth map and estimated depth map and compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, "memorize" is not a term we apply to the learning process, since it's not exact regurgitation of prior examples.

This is a matter of your experimental process.  You get to define the success criteria.  Is 95% accuracy good enough for your intended application?  What, to you, is good enough performance to declare success?

One way to build a more convincing argument is to make the typical third partition: besides training and test sets, save part of your data for validation.  You do the training and testing as you've already done.  When the model has converged, you apply it to the validation set to predict results.  If *that* test passes your success criterion, *then* you have a finished model.

Comment: Well the problem is. What kind of validation dataset would I have as I only have this one "object". If I train this object from all angles I cannot put anything in the validation dataset which would be differente from test or training dataset. Well I could put an image with view direction 5° horizontally and 7° vertically in the training dataset and 6° 7° in the test dataset and 7° 7° in the validation dataset but obviously they would all look really similar, so I think this wouldnt make a big difference.

Comment: You're reasoning in the wrong direction.  Your data set needs to guard the model's purpose.  Until you answer that issue, I can't offer any guidance on the data needed to test the model's fitness for that purpose.